# Probability of drawing no aces with replacement of cards?

Tags: probability, statistics

If you choose n cards with replacement (randomly
choose a card, note what it is in a list, replace it in the deck, and
repeat), then what is the probability that the list of cards contains
no aces?

I know that without replacement, the probability would be

Choose(48, n)/Choose (52, n)

I'm not sure what to do when there's replacement. Any help?

Comment: The probability of a non-Ace on a draw is $48/52$. The probability this happens $n$ times in a row is $(48/52)^n$. Or if you want to count, there are $52^n$ equally likely sequences of $n$ cards. There are $48^n$ sequences of non-Ace cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that the first card is not an ace is $P(A_1) = 48/52$. The probability that the second card is not an ace is $P(A_2) = 48/52$, and since this is an independent event to the first draw (thanks to drawing with replacement), the probability that neither card is an ace is $P(A_1\ and\ A_2) = P(A_1)P(A_2) = (48/52)^2$.

More generally, the probability that no card in $n$ draws is an ace is $P(A_1\ and\ A_2\ and\ A_3\ and \ldots\ and\ A_n) = (48/52)^n$.